# How to make font face work for HTML email on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, email, typeface

`@font-face` works perfectly on HTML email desktop version.
Then it comes to mobile. It look to me that Chrome and Gmail on iOS does't support `@font-face` much.
Any solutions?

Comment: Hi. Please step first to [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a guide on using font-face in html emails [here](https://templates.mailchimp.com/design/typography/)

Please be aware that not all desktop or mobile email clients support the use of the @font-face rule. Therefore, you should always provide a web-safe font as back up.

Comment: Sure, I figured it out. iOS email show font-face while Chrome and G-mail on iOS doesn't support.